# Consultas continuas a SQL Server

Tags: sql, vb.net

Edito para reformular la pregunta:

Tengo una aplicación que controla peticiones de material. Para ello hay una ventana en la que se cargan las peticiones pendientes de atender, con distintos filtros, como por ejemplo el Grupo que se encarga de atenderlas (podemos ver las peticiones pendientes de un Grupo en concreto).

Es una información que debería verse actualizada en tiempo real, para lo cual sólo se me ocurre lanzar una consulta que saque las peticiones pendientes cada pocos segundos (2, 3 segundos...)

`SELECT idPeticion, referenciaPeticion, tLimitePeticion, nombreGrupo
FROM PETICIONES INNER JOIN GRUPOS ON PETICIONES.idGrupo = GRUPOS.idGrupo
WHERE PETICIONES.idGrupo = 1`

No sé hasta qué punto una técnica así puede considerarse correcta. Intenté desarrollar un ejemplo con SQLDependency para que fuera el SGBD el que avisase a la aplicación de alguna modificación en la tabla, pero sólo conseguí que me avisase del primer cambio.

¿Es válida esta forma de proceder? ¿O hay alguna otra estrategia mejor?. Ahora mismo no conozco las características del Servidor, pero recibe peticiones constantemente, y no quiero desbordarlo o hacer que su rendimiento empeore realizando consultas constantes.

¿Podría de igual manera afectar al rendimiento de la web?. La consulta no debería devolver una cantidad muy elevada de datos.

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías aportar el código y características del servidor, te sugiero que redactes la pregunta siguiendo las directivas del sitio, puedes eguir el tour para conocer más en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: esta pregunta parece basada en opiniones, motivo por el cual pudiera terminar cerrada, revisa [ask]

Answer (score -1):

La pregunta es un poco abstracta, pero centrandome en esto:

> ¿Es posible realizar consultas a SQL Server cada dos o tres segundos?

La respuesta es SI, un servidor de SQL Server puede atender miles de peticiones por segundo, de múltiples usuarios, dependiendo el límite solo de configuración y  hardware. Para eso se crearon los DBMS, precisamente.

Ahora bien, para entender el problema que tiene tu caso necesitaríamos ver algo del código que hace las inserciones que mencionas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El código realmente no es más que una consulta que llena un grid. Pero es una información que debería verse en el mayor tiempo real posible.

Comment: Alli dependerá muchísimo de lo que se consulte, y el modo en que se ejecute esa consulta. SI la consulta se invoca permanentemente, y desde muchos clientes, puede terminar "penalizada" el servidor de BBDD, especialmente si no es propietario o dedicado.
Probablemente sea mejor idea sólo refrescar el grid cuando el grid mismo se visualiza, y hacer que lo actualice en base a una estimación de la media de tiempo entre transacciones que modifiquen datos.
No resulta útil modificar la vista si los datos no se han modificado.
En definitiva es un caso para analizar especificamente para tu escenario.